# UI-Grid not displaying JSON data?

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I have what I think is the correct accessor syntax for binding my UI-Grid control, I don't get any errors or any data. I just get a warning about Mutating the prototype.

My json data structure is like this:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "acctIdInfo": {
        "acctId": "257905480",
        "acctCode": "ABC10101102",
        "acctName": "BIG CORPORATION",
        "acctRole": [
          "C"
        ]
      },
      "acctNameAddr": {
        "addressLine": [
          "7280 JAMISON ST"
        ],
        "cityName": "VANCOUVER",
        "stateCd": "US-WA",
        "countryCd": "US",
        "postalCd": "97979"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

The code in my AngularJS controller to bind is:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ngResource'])

  .factory('jsonDataFactory', function ($resource) {
    return {
      custData: $resource('data.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
      }),

    };
  });

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$resource','jsonDataFactory',  function ($scope,$resource,  jsonDataFactory) {
  $scope.gridOptions = { 
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'acctIdInfo.acctId' },
    { name: 'acctIdInfo.acctCode'},
    { name: 'acctIdInfo.acctName'},
    { name: 'acctNameAddr.addressLine' }
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions.data = jsonDataFactory.custData.query().records;
  $scope.CustomerData = [];
  $scope.CustomerData = jsonDataFactory.custData.query();
  console.log($scope.CustomerData);
  $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.CustomerData.records;


}]);
```

Here is my [plnk of what I tried](http://plnkr.co/edit/rO9Xzh?p=info) -

I think I'm close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do assign a data to `ui-grid` data source once ajax call response comes back. I assumed that you had used `$resource`, so you can have promise over it to attach callback function.

```
jsonDataFactory.custData.query().$promise.then(function(response){
   $scope.CustomerData = response;
   console.log($scope.CustomerData);
   $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.CustomerData.records;
});
```

Comment: I tried just that @Pankaj Parkar but it tells me 'Error: jsonDataFactory.custData.query(...).then is not a function"

Comment: @haakon319 could you add `jsonDataFactory` code, also look at updated answer

Comment: Updated with the full script.js file from my plnk, were you able to see the plnkr?

Comment: @haakon319 no I can't see it.. did you try my updated answer?

Comment: I updated it so the plnk link works now. Sorry about that. I'm trying that code snippet now

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much! I knew I was close, well at least as far as my accessor goes. :)

Comment: @haakon319 Glad to help you. Thanks :-)